# Single graph with multiple instance values for same metric?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I am having 10 tomcat servers running on separate EC2 instance.

I can successfully create a graph for heap value of each tomcat server using the below command

mon-put-data --metric-name Heapmetric --namespace cloud --dimensions "InstanceId=i-444444" --unit Count --value 6000 --show-request

I am getting 10 graphs under the namespace "cloud" with the different instance id.

Is it possible to publish all the 10 instances heap metrics in a single graph based on instance id. If so what is the option i have to use in the mon-put-data?